# WebSphere MQ - error running runivt on fresh install

Tags: wcf, soap, ibm-mq

I am trying to execute the RUNIVT tests on a fresh install of Websphere MQ 7.5.0.2 for Windows, but hitting this error:

```
14/06/15 08:48:28 - Process(20900.1) User(bobble) Program(amqswsdl.exe) 
                      Host(bobblespc) Installation(Installation1) 
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2) 
AMQ9920: A SOAP Exception has been thrown. 

EXPLANATION: 
A SOAP method encountered a problem and has thrown an exception. Details of the 
exception are: 
'System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 
'MQSOAPHost'.    at MQWSDL.Main(String[] args)' 
ACTION: 
Investigate why the SOAP method threw the exception. 
----- MQWSDL.Main : 0 ---------------------------------------------------------
```

when the line:

```
amqswsdl "jms:/queue?destination=SOAPN.demos@WMQSOAP.DEMO.QM&connectionFactory=(connectQueueManager(WMQSOAP.DEMO.QM))&initialContextFactory=com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi&targetService=StockQuoteDotNet.asmx&replyDestination=SYSTEM.SOAP.RESPONSE.QUEUE" StockQuoteDotNet.asmx generated\StockQuoteDotNet_Wmq.wsdl
```

is called.

I cannot find any detail on the error or why I might be getting it? Any assistance gratefully received!

---

I found this in the bin folder - it's the redirect for the XMS namespace...and redirects to a version I don't have installed?  The WCF version redirects v6 & v7.0 to v7.5.

I don't know where or how this is installed - or where it's stored in Windows...but when I try and run any of the sample apps, they fall down as unable to load assembly v 2.5.0.2 of IBM.XMS

```
<configuration>
  <!-- 1.7 clients/dotnetclient/src/code/PublisherPolicy/XmsPublisherPolicy.config, netClient, nn00 -->
  <!-- Publisher policy file IBM.XMS -->
  <!-- Redirects to version 2.5.0.2 of the assembly. -->

  <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <!-- publisher policy for IBM.XMS.dll -->
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="IBM.XMS"
                           publicKeyToken="d2666ab12fca862b"
                           culture="Neutral" />

         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.1.2-2.5.0.2"
                          newVersion="2.5.0.2"/>
       </dependentAssembly>

        <!-- publisher policy for IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.dll -->
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="IBM.XMS.Client.Impl"
                            publicKeyToken="d2666ab12fca862b"
                            culture="Neutral" />

          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.1.2-2.5.0.2"
                           newVersion="2.5.0.2"/>
        </dependentAssembly>

        <!-- publisher policy for IBM.XMS.Provider.dll -->
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="IBM.XMS.Provider"
                            publicKeyToken="d2666ab12fca862b"
                            culture="Neutral" />

          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.1.2-2.5.0.2"
                           newVersion="2.5.0.2"/>
        </dependentAssembly>

        <!-- publisher policy for IBM.XMS.Util.dll -->
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="IBM.XMS.Util"
                            publicKeyToken="d2666ab12fca862b"
                            culture="Neutral" />

          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.1.1.2-2.5.0.2"
                           newVersion="2.5.0.2"/>
        </dependentAssembly>

      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When you say "fresh install of Websphere MQ 7" do you mean 7.0? 7.1? 7.5? With fix packs installed?  The .Net classes have been significantly enhanced version to version and there are many fixes in the service stream so it's ALWAYS important to know the version and fix pack on these questions.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I don't have the answer but Shashi, the resident MQ .Net expert, would have needed the version info to answer. Hopefully he's back in the office and will respond shortly.